# Finding bounding rect of rotated objects on dynamically created canvas or SVG with javascript (typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-maps, svg, canvas

I have a problem that I have been trying to solve for a while.

I am working on a web app with typescript, react and google maps, and for the markers I want to use a custom image that is created in runtime given more parameters.

The images has two objects, a circle and a triangle that points on direction by previously given angle and based on other parameters, they have different color.The images should be looking like:
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buI8D.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoSOh.png) .

The images can range from 1 to 300 depending on user choice. Other thing is that the top of the triangle should begin at the map coordinates, and when more markers are at close proximity, should be looking like in this picture [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Vz3I.png).

I have succeeded to create the images and place them on the map as desired, but my problem is that the images are too big and are overlapping when they are close, so all markers are not clickable until zoomed in, so I get situation like this: [Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vQM3.png).

I need to crop out the transparent area so only the circle and the triangle are left to use for the map. I have created two functions, one with canvas element and one with SVG element. They both are similar, First I draw the circle then the triangle and rotate them.

With the SVG solution I was able to find the bounding rect using `getBBox()` or `getBoundingClientRect()` but the problem is that the images are not loaded into the DOM and I get nothing from these methods until the SVG is added into the DOM, which is a not good because I should add every image into the DOM, then process it, add to the map and delete it from DOM.

With the canvas method I was able to find a function on the internet that loops through and scans every pixel from the canvas and return the objects, but when there are many elements loaded it is a little slow. I have also tried to find the objects by finding the rotated coordinates using this formula:

```
x1 = x * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) - y * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180)
y1 = x * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) + y * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180)
```

but not successful.

So what would be the best way to solve this problem?

Thank you.

The code:

```
    // draw canvas
    const drawMarkerIconCanvas = (
        angle?: number | null,
        arrowFillColor?: string,
        circleFillColor?: string,
        strokeColor?: string,
        scale?: number,
        text?: string,
        textColor?: string) => {
    
        angle = angle || null;
        arrowFillColor = arrowFillColor || "#000000";
        circleFillColor = circleFillColor || "#FACF00";
        strokeColor = strokeColor || "#0050b3";
        scale = scale || 0.7;
        text =  text || " ";
        textColor = textColor || "#FFFFFF";
    
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = 180;
        canvas.height = 180;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        if(ctx) {
            ctx.scale(scale,scale!)
            ctx.strokeStyle=strokeColor!;
            if(angle) {
                ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2,canvas.height / 2)
                ctx.rotate(angle! * Math.PI / 180)
                ctx.translate(-30, 0)
            }
            // draw the circle
            ctx.lineWidth=2;
            ctx.fillStyle=circleFillColor!;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(30,60,25,0,2*Math.PI);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            
            // draw the triangle
            ctx.fillStyle = arrowFillColor!;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(20, 30);
            ctx.lineTo(40, 30);
            ctx.lineTo(30, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(20, 30);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill()
            ctx.stroke()
    
            // draw the Text
            ctx.translate(30, 60)
            ctx.rotate(-angle! * Math.PI / 180)
            ctx.translate(-30, -60)
            ctx.font="14px Arial"
            ctx.fillStyle=textColor;
            ctx.fillText(text,27-ctx.measureText(text).width/2,63,)
        }
        return canvas.toDataURL();
    }

   // draw svg
    const drawMarkerIconSVG = (angle?: number | null,
                           arrowFillColor?: string,
                           circleFillColor?: string,
                           strokeColor?: string,
                           scale?: number,
                           text?: string,
                           textColor?: string) => {

    angle = angle || 0;
    arrowFillColor = arrowFillColor || "#000000";
    circleFillColor = circleFillColor || "#FACF00";
    strokeColor = strokeColor || "#0050b3";
    scale = scale || 0.7;
    text = text || " ";
    textColor = textColor || "#FFFFFF"

    const getBox = (element: any) => {
        return (element as SVGGraphicsElement).getBBox()
    }

    const svg: HTMLElement = document.createElement('svg')

    const group = document.createElement('g')

    const circle = document.createElement('circle')

    const poly = document.createElement('polygon')

    svg.setAttribute("xmlns","http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")

    circle.setAttribute('cx', '30')
    circle.setAttribute('cy', '60')
    circle.setAttribute('r', '25')
    circle.setAttribute('fill', circleFillColor)
    circle.setAttribute('stroke', strokeColor)
    circle.setAttribute('stroke-width', '2')

    poly.setAttribute('points', '20,30, 40,30,30,0')
    poly.setAttribute('fill', arrowFillColor);
    poly.setAttribute('stroke', strokeColor);
    poly.setAttribute('stroke-width', '2');

    group.appendChild(circle)
    group.appendChild(poly)

    group.setAttribute('transform', 'scale('+scale+') translate(90,90) rotate('+angle+') translate(-30,0)')


    const box = getBox(group)

    svg.appendChild(group)

    svg.setAttribute('viewBox', `${box.x-10} ${box.y-10} ${box.width+2} ${box.height+2}`)

    return svg
}
```

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding your problem.  So the problem that your Google Maps markers are overlapping each other?  In most situation like this, the typical approach is to replace the group of markers with a single marker. Usually it will show a count of how many markers it represents. Then you zoom in to resolve them better. Is there a reason you are not doing that?

Comment: @Paul thank you for your message, I know what you mean, but not what I needed. Anyway got the problem solved but I did not manage to respond sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little experimenting I was able to solve my problem, not the intended solution to find the bounds, but in my case worked for me. First I was drawing the images on the center of the canvas and then scaling them.  After that I placed them on the map with offset based on the angle of the rotation and the translation of the canvas, applying the aforementioned formula for finding points after rotation, so I have created a function like this:

```
const getCoordinates = (x: number, y: number, angle: number, imgWidth: number, imgHeight: number) => {
    let x1, y1;

    x1 = x * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) - y * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180)
    y1 = x * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) + y * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180)

    return {
        x: x1+imgWidth/2, y: y1+imgHeight/2
    }
}
```